# Need assistance with reading lines from text file to dict

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that takes a text file with lines in this format and turn it into a dict.

John
Doe
Bob
Cape

I need the first line to be the key, the next be the value for our blank dict.

Here is what I've attempted so far, I'm not really sure how to get one line to be the key and the next the value, for each first and last name. Thank you.

```
people = {}
with open('names.txt', 'r') as data:

    data = data.readlines()

    for line in data:
        line = line.strip()
        people[line] = ' '

    print(people)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over a **[range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges)** with a step size of 2:

```
people = {}

with open('names.txt', 'r') as file:
    # `read().splitlines()` removes the new line characters
    # from the ends of the lines in an efficient way
    lines = file.read().splitlines() 
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 2):
        people[lines[i]] = lines[i + 1]

print(people)
```

**Output:**

```
{'John': 'Doe', 'Bob': 'Cape'}
```

Try it out **[here](https://repl.it/repls/ElaborateHotMonad)**.